# T-SQL stored procedure with parameters using with MDX

Tags: t-sql, mdx, olap-cube

I created stored procedure in T-SQL with parameters. How can use this parameters in MDX to define route to file where OLAP cube is localized and in 'WHERE' condition? This is my query below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PaymentMethod] 
(
    @AccountID BIGINT,
    @LocationID BIGINT  
)
AS
BEGIN    
SELECT N'Names' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), "[Basic].[Payment Method].[Payment Method].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"),
        N'Revenue'= CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),CAST("[Measures].[Revenue]" AS FLOAT)) FROM OPENQUERY([LG], 
        'WITH MEMBER [Measures].[DateFilter] AS   ''CDATE([Date.H_Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE)'', SOLVE_ORDER = 0, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE MEMBER [Basic].[Payment Method].[All].[ChequePayment] AS   ''[Basic].[Payment Method].[Amex] + [Basic].[Payment Method].[Master] +    [Basic].[Payment Method].[Visa]'', SOLVE_ORDER = 0, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE 

    SELECT {[Measures].[Revenue]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS, 
        NON EMPTY Filter(NonEmpty(CROSSJOIN({[Basic].[Payment Method].&[Cash],        
                                                                                                    [Basic].[Payment Method].[All].[ChequePayment]},       
                                                                                                    [Date].[H_Date].[Month].AllMembers),     
                                                                                                    {[Measures].[Revenue]}),   
                                                                                                    DATEADD("m",-1,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526))) <= [Measures].[DateFilter] AND [Measures].[DateFilter] < DATEADD("m",0,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526)))) 
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_CAPTION] ON ROWS 

FROM [OLAPProject_@AccountID].[SummaryCube_@AccountID] 
WHERE ([Location].[LocationName].&[@LocationID])');
```

The parameters are used only in the end of query in 'FROM' and 'WHERE' clause. The name of project OLAP cube is "OLAPProject_@AccountID". How can I use this parametr to open the right project in query?

Answer (score 1):

You can structure the query like the following and just use normal 'Dynamic SQL' if you need to feed parameters into the string @mdxString:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PaymentMethod] 
(
    @AccountID BIGINT,
    @LocationID BIGINT  
)
AS
BEGIN    


DECLARE @mdxString AS NVARCHAR(3000);
SET @mdxString = 
'
        WITH MEMBER [Measures].[DateFilter] AS   ''CDATE([Date.H_Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE)'', SOLVE_ORDER = 0, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE MEMBER [Basic].[Payment Method].[All].[ChequePayment] AS   ''[Basic].[Payment Method].[Amex] + [Basic].[Payment Method].[Master] +    [Basic].[Payment Method].[Visa]'', SOLVE_ORDER = 0, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE 
        SELECT 
            {[Measures].[Revenue]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS, 
        NON EMPTY Filter(NonEmpty(CROSSJOIN({[Basic].[Payment Method].&[Cash],        
        [Basic].[Payment Method].[All].[ChequePayment]},       
        [Date].[H_Date].[Month].AllMembers),     
        {[Measures].[Revenue]}),   
        DATEADD("m",-1,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526))) <= [Measures].[DateFilter] AND [Measures].[DateFilter] < DATEADD("m",0,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526)))) 
                DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_CAPTION] ON ROWS 
    FROM [OLAPProject_@AccountID].[SummaryCube_@AccountID] 
    WHERE ([Location].[LocationName].&[@LocationID])
'



SELECT 
    Names   = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), "[Basic].[Payment Method].[Payment Method].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"),
    Revenue = CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),CAST("[Measures].[Revenue]" AS FLOAT)) 
    FROM 
    OPENQUERY(
    [LG], 
    @mdxString  
);

END;
```

Comment: The parameters don't work like that, i guess you will have to concatenate them in the @mdxString. Other than that. This is the way.

Comment: @mxix hey up - I know the parameters do not work like that - just being a little playful: if the user sticks "dynamic sql" in Google there will be lots of help in how to take the parameters out of the string.